# What is the fatest way to rapidly grep data inside a panda dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

We have a Dataframe that holds over 1M Windows event logs.

One of the columns, called `data`, is used to store the relevant details we want to capture for each event log. For example:

`SubjectUserName=myuser, SubjectDomainName=XX, TargetUserName=XXXXX, TargetDomainName=XXXXX`

What is the fastest way to iterate over the dataframe's column `data` to download the entire list of `SubjectUserName` using a regular expression and store the results in an array?

We've tried traditional iteration methods such as `iterrows()`, but those proved rather slow when dealing with such a large amount of data.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Kind Regards, Alexander.

Comment: It is better to provide a sample of the actual data.  Or something representative such that I can create a test dataframe and try any solution I might propose.

Comment: If `SubjectUserName` etc. are the relevant details, store them as entries in separate columns (and/or indices), instead of storing them in one column together. It seems like your data structure is not designed for what you want to use it for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you can use [`str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
print (df)
                                                data
0  SubjectUserName=myuser, SubjectDomainName=XX, ...
1  SubjectUserName=myuser, SubjectDomainName=XX, ...

#temporaly display with of one column to 100
with pd.option_context('display.max_colwidth', 100):
    print (df.data)
0    SubjectUserName=myuser, SubjectDomainName=XX, TargetUserName=XXXXX, TargetDomainName=XXXXX
1    SubjectUserName=myuser, SubjectDomainName=XX, TargetUserName=XXXXX, TargetDomainName=XXXXX
Name: data, dtype: object


print (df.data.str.extract('SubjectUserName=(.*), SubjectDomainName', expand=False))
        0
0  myuser
1  myuser
```

Another possible solution is use [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) and split data by `,` (default separator) to `4` columns and then [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas.compat import StringIO

temp=u"""SubjectUserName=myuser, SubjectDomainName=XX, TargetUserName=XXXXX, TargetDomainName=XXXXX
SubjectUserName=myuser, SubjectDomainName=XX, TargetUserName=XXXXX, TargetDomainName=XXXXX
"""
#after testing replace 'StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), skipinitialspace=True, names=['SubjectUserName','SubjectDomainName','TargetUserName','TargetDomainName'])
print (df)
          SubjectUserName     SubjectDomainName        TargetUserName  \
0  SubjectUserName=myuser  SubjectDomainName=XX  TargetUserName=XXXXX   
1  SubjectUserName=myuser  SubjectDomainName=XX  TargetUserName=XXXXX   

         TargetDomainName  
0  TargetDomainName=XXXXX  
1  TargetDomainName=XXXXX 


print (df.SubjectUserName.str.replace('SubjectUserName=', ''))
0    myuser
1    myuser
Name: SubjectUserName, dtype: object
```

Comment: Lol. Did you made it up? Or others also use ?

Comment: data.str.extract() turned out to be the easiest and fastest solution. Thanks!

Comment: @AlexanderPerchov - Thank you for accepting and nice day

Answer (score 0):

First, Its true that for large datasets, pandas need much time to process and I also went through the same phase. I can suggest you a small trick that really helped me.

First, for one time, let data load on dataframe. Then making another list of column, select all columns you need and from your dataframe, make your own dataset(Ex- .xls or .csv or .json file). You will find that size of your created dataset is far smaller in size than original dataset you were working with.  Original datasets have many unused information and contents which are never used and significantly take much memory than needed. I understand, this is not standard way but it really helped me.
For Example:

```
df.to_csv('df1.csv')
```

You can also improvise your selected columns and make better choices for smaller dataset. Example:

```
new_cols = ['Name', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
df.columns = new_cols
```

This really helped me. I hope it may help you as well.